# Parse.com: storing Pointer to class in PHP does not work

Tags: php, pointers, parse-platform

I´m trying to achieve to store a pointer to a custom class in parse.com PHP.
I crawled through the internet and did find something like that:

```
$storeObj = new ParseObject("_Store");
$storeObj->specials = $store->dataType('pointer',array('_Specials', "$spec_id"));
```

All classes are set up:
"_Store" has a column of type pointer and is named "specials". I have a class "_Specials" where "specials" should point to.

So what am i doing wrong here?
Does anybody have another solution for storing pointers into classes?

Cheers, Tomte

Comment: The documentation has an example for that here https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#objects-pointers. Have you tried that yet? If yes and it didn't work, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, thats it! Just setting the whole ParseObject of the pointed class did the trick! Sometimes the easiest things can become complicated...doohh! Please provide an Answer and i will mark it as solved. Thanks!